# Why set function in the mutableList not set the element? Kotlin

Tags: android, algorithm, kotlin

I am trying to switch old element from the list to a new element of the list and put it on the same spot as old one by index. But its not setting it

```
val foundIndex = todoItemList.value?.indexOfFirst { it.id == item.id }
    foundIndex?.let {
       val list = todoItemList.value?.toMutableList()
        list?.set(it, item)
    }
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the resulting `list`. It is created and then immediately garbage-collected. Didn't you plan to assign it to `todoItemList.value` at the end?

Comment: @broot how can i make it switch the element then?

Comment: If `todoItemList.value` is a `List` and not `MutableList`, then it is read-only, you can't modify it. If this property is a `var`, then you can replace the whole list with a new value. Below `list?.set()` line add this: `todoItemList.value = list`.

Comment: @broot but how to remove / update needed item from one list and get the new list with updated item?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. You already did this: you created a new list and updated it. You just don't use this new list anywhere.

Comment: @broot logs shows that its not updating the list with new item

Comment: @broot Thats whole code

Comment: @broot  val foundIndex = todoItemList.value?.indexOfFirst { it.id == item.id }
        foundIndex?.let { it ->
            val list = todoItemList.value?.toMutableList()
            list?.set(it, item)
            list?.let {
                todoItemList.postValue(it)
                roomManager.editItem(item)
            }
        }

Comment: All these `?.` obfuscate the code and make it harder to reason as we have to assume parts of the code are not executed. I would replace this with a single check for null at the beginning. But anyway, this code looks fine, I think it should update the live data. How do you observe it did not, where/when do you log the new value? Note it doesn't update immediately, but posts updating on a main thread, so it should happen soon, but you won't see it yet if adding logs e.g. below this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// the comments below your question are rigth
// you just have to assign a new list to your `todoItemList` like this

val foundIndex = todoItemList.value?.indexOfFirst { it.id == item.id }
                foundIndex?.let {
val list = todoItemList.value?.toMutableList() // here you are creating a new instance of list - MutableList
   list?.set(it, item) // here you are working with your new list, setting item to foundIndex in a new list
}    
todoItemList.value = list // you have to assign your new list to todoItemList.value 
//in case if value in todoItemList's class declared as vaR not vaL, 

//otherwise you have to copy your whole todoItemList object with a new list, something like this 
todoItemList = TodoItemListClass(value = list)
```